# How do I add a remove, adding, and edit function to my menu?

Tags: python-3.x

Struggling to find a solution please explain in a way that I can learn, sorry for the inconvience. This is all I have done for now, I can't really find a way to make it work.

```
print('Welcome to the Team Manager')
def mainmenu():
print('---------Main Menu----------')
option = input("""
        1:Display Team Roster.

        2. Add Member.

        3. Remove Member.

        4. Edit Member.

        5. Exit Program.

        Enter one of the following numbers to choose an option:  """)
if option == "1":
    roster()
elif option == "2":
    addmember()
elif option == "3":
    removemember()
elif option == "4":
    editmember()
elif option == "5":
    sys.exit()

def roster():
    roster = ['Toby','Susan','Jerry','Jimmy','Tom','Bob','Jake','Alex','Hannah']
    print("Current Team Roster",roster)
def addmember():
    roster = ['Toby','Susan','Jerry','Jimmy','Tom','Bob','Jake','Alex','Hannah']
    addnmember = int("Add New Member:  ")
    currentroster = roster + addnmember
    print(currentroster)
def removemember():
    roster = ['Toby','Susan','Jerry','Jimmy','Tom','Bob','Jake','Alex','Hannah']
    rmember = input('Enter name of the member you wish to remove: ')
    newroster = roster - rmember
```

mainmenu()

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should take a look on `list` methods, as you can find in Python documentation: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html

Now, specifically for your question:

1. Add -> Use `append` method:

```
roster.append(NewElementToBeAdded)
```

2. Remove -> Use `remove` method:

```
roster.append(NewElementToBeAdded)
```

3. Edit -> Use `index` method to find the element in the list, and if finds, you can assign directly the new value to it using the function `insert` in order to maintain the same position:

```
element = "Susan"
newValue = "Abc"
if element in roster:
    idx = roster.index(element)
    roster.remove(element)
    roster.insert(idx, newValue)
```

One thing about comparing `strings` is that they are case sensitive, so if you user types `susan` instead of `Susan`, it won't be identified as a valid element. So my suggestion for fixing is to compare values in lower case, using the method `lower()` from Strings, and the only "complex" thing you should do, is using a list comprehension to compare only to your `roster` list in lower case as well. Also, you should use the `capitalize()` function to ensure that when you try to operate on your `list`, the element is right formatted what gives us: (you could just create your list with lower case strings and capitalize when printing to avoid this, as well)

```
element = "susan"
newValue = "Abc"

if element.lower() in [member.lower() for member in roster]:
    elementCapitalized = element.lower().capitalize()
    idx = roster.index(elementCapitalized)
    roster.remove(elementCapitalized)
    roster.insert(idx, newValue)
```

Last thing, if you want to reuse this function inside a loop, take out your list outside the loop, in order to create the beginning members, and then just add this `list` as an argument for your functions, otherwise, the way is written, your list will always have the same values after each loop.

PS: Your question was not a good one, but since you're new here, I suggest to read the articles about how to create good questions and what's accepted by the community:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking

Comment: sorry idk a lot about this website and the community but i will keep that in mind